# Solution for OnPointerExit() Triggering on Touch Release On Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch, mouseevent

I have created some custom radial menu buttons for my Android game. The radial menu displays when the game object with the menu is touched. I'm using mouse events to activate the menu, which works in Unity and also when built to Android. When the menu is active, you can mouse or slide over a menu item to select it. If you then release on that menu item, it will pass the selection to the radial menu, which then takes the appropriate action.

The following works in Unity:

```
public void OnPointerEnter (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    myMenu.selected = this;
    Debug.Log ("Menu selection is now: " + this.action.ToString ());
    defaultColor = circle.color;
    circle.color = Color.white;
}

public void OnPointerExit (PointerEventData eventData)
{
    myMenu.selected = null;
    Debug.Log ("Menu selection has been nulled out.");
    circle.color = defaultColor;
}
```

However, it does not work correctly when built to Android. Via some debug testing, I've determined that in Unity, if I activate the menu and mouse over a menu item, then release the mouse, myMenu.selected is correctly assigned. However, on Android only, lifting my finger over the menu item processes a final OnPointerExit, which nulls it out, meaning that menu never gets a proper selection. The mouse does not behave this way--it doesn't treat the pointer as having exited when the mouse button is released.

I can "solve" this problem by switching everything to touch, but then I cannot test using the Unity player and my mouse. So far, everything via mouse also worked correctly via touch. This is the first issue I've run into. Is there any clean solution for this? Or is the best solution to use macros to determine if I'm in the editor and have separate mouse and touch code for each?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the behavior you trying to implement.

Touch input does not have the notion of "hover" so you should probably be using the `IPointerClickHandler` interface and/or the `IPointerDownHandler` and `IPointerUpHandler` interfaces instead.

I recommend separating the *hover* logic vs *touch/click* clearly by using the preprocessor directive `#if UNITY_STANDALONE` around your hover-code.

Comment: There's no hover logic. I am using iPointerEnterHandler and ExitHandler. The logic goes like this:
- Touch object to open menu.
- Slide while touching to preferred menu item.
- Sliding off of menu items sets the preferred menu item to null (no selection).
- Release while on that menu item to select it.

The problem is that on Android, but not in the player, releasing while on the menu item is treating it as exiting.

I think your solution still works, however, which is to use a preprocessor directive to use touch instead of mouse events outside standalone for predictability.

Comment: Seem's there is something missing from your comment. It would help if you edited the question to include the rest of your interaction code.